# Protractor - Shard By Suite

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

It looks like Protractor currently allows you to shard by file. Is there way to split it up by suite, if there are files within each suite that are order dependent (each suite being independent)?

Comment: protractor ca n run a single spec, if you pass a string with a path to the file. If you pass an array of strings, where each item is a path to a spec, then it'll run it as suite. Refer to https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality might be achievable by setting multiple capabilities each with their own specs property containing only scripts from a particular suite.

Each capability would not be sharded so all tests in each capability would run in sequence but each capability would run parallel.

`maxSessions:5` allows 5 capabilities to run at the same time

```
  maxSessions: 5,
  multiCapabilities: [
    {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      maxInstances: 1,
      specs: [
        '../suite1/test1.js',
        '../suite1/test2.js',
        '...',
      ],
    },
    {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      maxInstances: 1,
      specs: [
        '../suite2/test1.js',
        '../suite2/test2.js',
        '...,'
      ],
    },
  ]
```