# Webdriver io running in Parallel - How to ensure one test spec runs before another one - execution order

Tags: mocha.js, webdriver-io

I have inherited a webdriver io - mocha test framework. Until now the tests have been ran one at a time. There was one test spec that had to be ran before the other. This was just handled in the file naming convention:

```
aFirstTest.js
xLastTest.js
```

So when the whole suite was ran, this ensured that aFirstTest.js was ran before xLastTest.js

I now want to run the tests in parallel mode.

How can I ensure that aFirstTest.js is ran before xLastTest.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61941653/protractor-shard-by-suite) might give you some ideas.

Otherwise, you'd need to present the specs to WebdriverIO as one. An easy way to do this would be wrapping them in another file.

**wrapper.spec.js**:

```
const first = require('./aFirstTest')
const last = require('./xLastTest')
```

And in your config:

```
suites: {
        firstLast: [
            './specs/wrapper.spec.js'
        ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks paintedgreen