# WebdriverIO - How to run one test before all other tests (which should run parallely)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, npm, webdriver, e2e-testing, webdriver-io

I am using Webdriver.io & I have 4 test files.

`a.test.ts`, `b.test.ts`, `c.test.ts`, `d.test.ts`.

My question is, how can I run the tests such that at first only (not any other test cases) `a.test.ts` runs and then all 3 tests run in parallel.

```
                     |-- b.test.ts
Start - a.test.ts ---|-- c.test.ts
                     |-- d.test.ts
```

Is there any way to do this ??

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63537142/23182657). Seems to be a similar question